# mongoose nodejs How to delete Project from DB and from User projects array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My app have a User that contains an array of Projects, and when I click to open one single project, I have a button 'delete' so I can delete that project (by its ID). That works, but my problem is: 
**I can delete the Project from database but I can't delete that project from User array projects where it keeps projects ID.**

**Here's my User Schema:**

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");


let passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   username: String,
   password: String,
   companyname: String,
   companyimageURL: String,
   projects: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Project'
  }] 
});


UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**my Project Schema:**

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

let projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   projectname: String,
   typeofproject: String,
   imageURL: String,
   dateMonthFrom: String,
   dateYearFrom: String,
   dateMonthTo: String,
   dateYearTo: String,
   tasks: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tasks'    
   }],
   user: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
   }] 
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

**and my server side:** I think I have this all wrong! this was what I tried to do by finding that project by Id and delete and then finding the user by id and update, but this don't work.

```
//Delete Project
app.delete('/dashboard/project/:id/edit', (req, res) => {
let id = req.params.id;
let userid = req.user._id;


let project = {
    projectname: req.body.projectname,
    typeofproject: req.body.typeofproject,
    imageURL: req.body.imageURL,
    dateMonthFrom: req.body.dateMonthFrom,
    dateYearFrom: req.body.dateYearFrom,
    dateMonthTo: req.body.dateMonthTo,
    dateYearTo: req.body.dateYearTo,
}; 

Project.findByIdAndDelete(id, (err) =>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(userid, {$set:project}, {new: true},(err) => {
            if(err){
                 console.log(err)
            }
            console.log('Project Deleted: ' + id)
            res.redirect('/dashboard#/projects');
         });
    });
 };
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$pull` operator. Visit [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) page for more details.

Your `user` update query should look like:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  userid,
  { $pull: { projects: id } },
  { new: true }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it works! My Result:

```
app.delete('/dashboard/project/:id/edit', (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let userid = req.user._id;



Project.findByIdAndDelete(id, (err) =>{
    console.log('deleting project', id)
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }

        User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            userid, 
            { $pull: { projects: id} }, 
            { new: true },(err) => {
                if(err){
                     console.log(err)
                }

                console.log('Project Deleted: ' + id)
                res.redirect('/dashboard#/projects');
       })
   })
};
```